# How can I select this button from the Chrome Console?

Tags: javascript

I have this button on my working program, called "Break" it's situated in a Dropdown list.

I am working on a administrated Chromebox so the Chrome Console is all I have. I want to select the dropdown menu and select the status "Break" from the Chrome console.

Untill now I can only access the dropdown using this code `document.evaluate("//button[@aria-label='Page options dropdown']",document).iterateNext().click();`

But I don't know how to select the status "Break".

This is the code for the break button from the Chrome Console[image]

How can I access that button ?

Comment: You can find elements by id, classname or tagName. Best is to use `document.querySelector` and pass a CSS query selector for the button you want. E.g. If you want to click "Ask Question" button on this page, then you can do it in chrome console as `document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/questions/ask']")[0].click()`

Comment: Hello Aditya, I understand but the problem is that I have tried to inspect that button ( see picture ahead) And there is no path for that button. If you can see in the code that i screenshoted, the only path for the button is "<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" ... this is where it starts to be difficult... because i cannot give that button the functinon .click();

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `break` button using the class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("._pf93iy").on('click', function(){
       alert('You clicked break button');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Lokesh, but the problems is that all the buttons from the dropdown ( Break, Lunch, etc) have the same class ("._pf93iy") <- this one

Comment: we need a unique id or class name to find a particular button.
Please post the code of all the buttons you have.